# Importing CSV file into Google Colab using numpy loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, import, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to migrate a JupyterLab notebook to Google Colab. In JupyterLab, when I have the notebook file and the associated csv files in the same directory, it is easy to import the data using numpy's loadtxt function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
filein = "testfile.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(open(filein, "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
```

For various reasons I'd like to continue to use np.loadtxt in Colab. However when I try the same code there, it can't find the csv file despite it residing in the same Google Drive location as the notebook file. I get this error: `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testfile.csv'"`.

I gather I somehow need to provide a path to the file, but haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Is there any straightforward way to use np.loadtxt?

Comment: Interestingly, this approach works perfectly well on Microsoft Azure Notebook.

Comment: Try `os.listdir(".")`, see what you find.

Comment: @RockyLi I get ['.config', 'sample_data'] as a result. I see neither of these files in the google drive folder the notebook is in so it must be running in some other directory.

Comment: what does `os.getcwd()`outputs? and what is the directory of `testfile.csv`?

Comment: When I type `os.getcwd()` into the notebook, I get: `'/content'`. I've placed the file `testfile.csv` into the same directory as the Jupyter notebook file which is in my google drive at: `My Drive>Colab Notebooks`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Colab doesn't automatically mount Google Drive. By default, the working directory is `/content` on an ephemeral backend virtual machine.

To access your file in Drive, you'll need to mount it first using the following snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then, `%cd /content/gdrive/My\ Drive` to change the working directory to your Drive root. (Or, customize the path as needed to wherever `testfile.csv` is located.)

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was close, but didn't do the `%cd`.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter and without command

```
# mount gdrive with this code
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
#below where the file is in gdrive, change with your
data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/test/"
yearsBase, meanBase = np.loadtxt(data_path + 'file.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

done, no other code needed
ciao

Comment: it does ask for confirmation though

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that has lesser manual intervention. This is more useful if you intend to run the colab notebook for a long time across multiple disconnected sessions so that you don't need to manually upload the file every time.

1. Upload the text file to google drive. Click share and obtain the shareable link. For example, this is an example shareable link for the file iris.csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Llp483f91dAJriuE6PanmecLA9sWDPyi/view
2. Copy the file ID from the above link. In this case, it is `1Llp483f91dAJriuE6PanmecLA9sWDPyi`
3. Now you can download the file using the below cell in any colab notebook:

   ```
   file_id = "1Llp483f91dAJriuE6PanmecLA9sWDPyi" # replace with your ID
   !gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file_id}
   ```

Type `!ls` to see the file in your workspace.

For a detailed official guide, refer this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Comment: This is interesting. The file is permanently uploaded to my google drive so that doesn’t have to be done each time. The reason I’m considering Google colab over Microsoft Azure notebook is that I want the notebook and data files accessible only by specific users and not publicly available.